# How do I pass in parameters when triggering a custom event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to convert the following jQuery code to pure JavaScript:

```
$(document).trigger('myCustomEvent', v2.first, v2.last);
```

Where `v2` is an object containing data I want to pass in as parameters when triggering this custom event.

**What I've tried**:

```
let myEvent = CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', {'detail': [v2.first, v2.last]});

document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function (e) {
  return e.detail;
}, false);
```

**My concerns**:

- The data won't be passed the same way as in the jQuery code
- Browser compatibility. I need to support IE 9+ and don't want to use any polyfills. So I may need to use an approach that's friendlier to IE...

Is there a better approach I should be using?

Comment: FYI: In your code sample. You broadcasted the event before you attached the listener. You should call `addEventListener` before you call `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your code example is not IE9 compatible. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but if you follow JavaScript 1.5 (ECMAScript 5) standard you should be okay.

Comment: Microsoft as a published list of compatibility for JS by IE version here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/javascript-version-information